# Is there a difference between command line tool and models that are trained using API (Programmatically)?

Tags: opennlp

In opennlp, I am training a named entity model. If I provide the ".train" file and train using the command line tool, it works perfect. But when I use the API and pass through sentence detector and tokenize it and send it to namefind, the find does not detect the types.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get it using the getType method from the Span?

http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.recognition.api

Also, you can refer to the command line tool source code to check if you are using it right:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/cmdline/namefind/TokenNameFinderTool.java?view=markup

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using the getType method using the Span object. I will go through the link provided by you once more and keep you posted for sure. Sorry for the delay in responding. Got into traveling for bread and did not get to see the response. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the "command-line code". Didn't fully solve my problem, but did help me out a bit!